# How do I make JTextArea always show the scroll bar (in Java)?

Tags: java, user-interface

Here is my code snippet:

```
JTextArea jta = new JTextArea();
JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(jta);
jsp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

It shows the scroll to the right but only shows the up and down arrows. How do I make the actual scroll bar to be always visible from the beginning?

Comment: `How do I make the actual scroll bar to be always visible from the beginning?` add data to the text area so that the data is greater than the size of the text area. If there is no data to scroll there is no need for the thumb knob to be painted since the size of the knob is based on the amount of data, when scrolling is required.

Comment: @camickr I understand but is there a way around it by making the thumb knob to be visible at all times?

Comment: The "thumb knob" is part of the UI. If you want to change this then you need to override the painting code of the UI to provide your own custom implementation. I see no reason to this since the default implementation is the implementation that users are familiar with.